# Setting query param value based on input field value in ember 2.8

Tags: ember.js

So I have a home.hbs template that looks like so:

```
<div>
  {{input type="number" min="2" max="24"}}
  {{#link-to 'game' (query-params cards="" class="button"}}
    Let's Play!
  {{/link-to}}
</div>
```

And I have a (not yet implemented) game route that will use a component to build up a game instance (which i pass with the 'cards' attribute). The thing is, the game route needs the value of the input field in this template to build this instance. Can i just do something like?:

```
{{#link-to 'game' (query-params cards={this.input.value} class="button"}}
```

Or is there a more efficient way to pass that number to the /game route? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, you can add property to route controller (`inputValue` for example) and bound it to input value. And then use it in `link-to` helper.

Something like below (didn't check it in real app):

```
{{input type="number" min="2" max="24" value=inputValue}}
{{#link-to 'game' (query-params cards=inputValue class="button"}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you suggest the game route be a nested route or would it work if the game route is also a global route? Put a different way, is it better to do /home/game?query-params or just /game?query-params ?

Comment: It is hard to give you advice about this w/o knowing the whole idea and architecture. IMHO, nested routes may be used when it needs by logic. For example, route `game` may have routes `game\rpg`, `game\fps` and go on.

Comment: @GiancarloManuelGuerraSalvá you should accept the answer :)